# Weird artifacts only in rendermode?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency

I've ran into some troubles while rendering transparent materials. These issues only occur when using
rendermode (F12). All render settings are default. I'm rendering on a GPU (Nvidia GTX 1070).

[image]

In viewport previews seem to be just fine and don't have the triangulated white faces

[image]

Here's the outliner and the shader used, maybe that could help solve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Subdivsion modifier with different level between viewport and render?

Comment: Subd modifier level are 2 for render and viewport.

Comment: The schrinkwrap modifiers are disabled in viewports (but not in render).

Comment: I completly missed that the shrinkwrap modifiers were turned off in viewport but not in rendermode. Disabling them fixed the issue - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The schrinkwrap modifiers are disabled in viewports but not for rendering:

[image]